# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo exception when using SherlockFragmentActivity .

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest

I am new in android . I tried to create a tab with SherlockFragmentActivity.
but when I run it it forced close because of this exception :
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

what is my problem ? is there any problem in add library ? or I should add SherlockFragmentActivity and SherlockFragment to my manifest ? or something else ...

thanks for any help .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="behrad.android.test.sherlock"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: Make sure you apply Sherlock theme as parent theme.

Comment: excuse me . I am new as I told . what should I do exactly ?:)

Comment: I've posted detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
you should use Sherlock theme.

**Solution:**

As stated in your manifest file, you are using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` ,

- Replace `AppTheme` with anyone from below:

`Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, or `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`

- Or you can `set it as Parent theme of AppTheme` inside `styles.xml` file

**Reference:**

In order for the custom action bar implementation to function your application must use `Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, or `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, or `your custom theme must use one of the aforementioned as its parent`.

[Sherlock Theme](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)